# Failed to open sambashare error

Tags: samba

I installed Sambashare using these instructions on two computers https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba#3

I click on my samba sharefolder and this window pops up asking for a domain which is prefilled to PAULGROUP https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6c7N.png

However when I enter the password it says Failed to open sambashare https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RM5w.png

This is probably user error I am quite new to Linux

Comment: Post the results of `testparm -s` (run from your Samba server); add to your question.

Comment: sorry for delay, here are results

Comment: testparm -sLoad smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'share' for parameter 'security'
Error loading services.